# Python 3 For/While Loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

Apologies in advanced, I'm quite new to Python. But, I need to create a program that calculates the amount of money a person would earn over a period of time if his or her slaary is one penny the first day, two pennies the second day and it continues to double for each day. I know I should use for & while loops, I'm just not entirely sure how to execute it.

So far I have this:

```
day = int(input('How many days did you work?: '))
start = 1
end = day
amount_start = 0.01

print()
print('Day     Amount ($)')
print('---     ----------')

for day in range(start, end + 1):
    amount_end = amount_start * 2
    for amount_start in (amount_start, amount_end):
        print(day, amount_end, sep='         ')
```

When I ran it, I saw that the starting number on day 1 was 0.02, and it duplicated each line twice. Any advice on what to change/add so I can understand this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll explain what your code does and then, what code would do what you want.

```
day = int(input('How many days did you work?: '))
start = 1
end = day
amount = 0.01 # Start and End shouldn't be a thing
total = 0 # I think this is what you wanted... the amount will double every time and the total will be increased by the amount every time

print()
print('Day     Amount ($)')
print('---     ----------')
```

Initialisation there, nothing wrong. Now, let's take a look on the two for loops.

```
for day in range(start, end + 1):
    amount_end = amount_start * 2
    for amount_start in (amount_start, amount_end):
        print(day, amount_end, sep='         ')
```

First, I'll recommend not to take care of the name of the variables. The variable `day` was already defined earlier, but as it is not used anymore for its original purpose, it doesn't matter much here.

The outer loop will be looped through the number of times you inputed earlier. Nothing wrong here either.
We then set the value of `amount_end` to twice the current value for `amount_start`.

Now, let's take a look at the inner loop. Here, the value of `amount_start` will go through the list `(amount_start, amount_end)`.
We'll loop twice in this loop, first with `amount_start` keeping its initial value, then with `amount_start` taking `amount_end`'s value.
This loop would be the same as

```
amount_start = amount_start
print(day, amount_end, sep='         ')
amount_start = amount_end
print(day, amount_end, sep='         ')
```

You can then see why it prints the same line twice.

In order to remove the duplication, and make the code more readable, I suggest the following code :

```
day = int(input('How many days did you work?: '))
start = 1
end = day
amount_start = 0.01

print()
print('Day     Amount ($)')
print('---     ----------')

for day in range(start, end + 1):
    amount_end = amount_start * 2
    print(day, amount_end, sep='         ')
    amount_start = amount_end
```

Do not hesitate to ask if you have any question about my answer. I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and precise explanation of this. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't nest the for loop

You should only have one for loop:

```
day = int(input('How many days did you work?: '))
start = 1
end = day
amount = 0.01 # Start and End shouldn't be a thing
total = 0 # I think this is what you wanted... the amount will double every time and the total will be increased by the amount every time

print()
print('Day     Amount ($)')
print('---     ----------')

for day in range(start, end + 1):
    total += amount # Give the person salary
    print(day, total, sep='         ') # Print the total amount of money earned
    amount *= 2 # Double the salary
```